# how to find width of font?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx, gdi

I'm using directx to draw my string, directx uses GDI to draw the string..
I'm using `DrawText` to draw my string.  I need a way to find the width of the string.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DrawText can calculate it for you. See the DT_CALCRECT flag:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Measure three times before you cut.  Once will do.

Comment: DT_CALCRECT won't draw the text, it will just tell you how big the rectangle the text would be drawn in will be.  You still have to call DrawText to actually draw the text after calculating its size.

Comment: I'm working with right now but something weird is happing, when i store the number of px. it always returns 19 ..

Comment: i'm getting the height how do i get the width?

Comment: @Ramilol, DT_CALCRECT gives you the width (see the description of it in the MSDN page I linked). If it isn't giving you the width you have probably passed some flags which force DrawText to fit the text into the rect you give (e.g. you haven't told DrawText to use a single line without line-wrapping).

Answer (score 5):

You mean [this DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx)? If so, it has a `DT_CALCRECT` flag that allows you to calculate the size of the text to draw.